# Payroll Array Java Calculation

Tags: java

**Hello guys, this is my first time i post something in here and i just started learning java. This is my assignment and i need to write a payroll code with array. However, i dont understand why i cant get it to work. Somehow, it only calculate the last employee, the first and second are not included. If you guys can help i'd appreciate it. Thank you!**

```
public class ArrayIG 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 3;

        //creating array

        int[]hours = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
        int[] employeeID = {5678459, 4520125, 7895122};
        double payRate;
        double wages = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your " + NUM_EMPLOYEES + " employees work hours and pay rate:");


        //get the hours
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Employee #" + employeeID[i] + ": ");
            hours[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

            //get the hourly pay rate
            System.out.print("Enter the pay rate: ");
            payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

            wages = hours[i] * payRate;
        }



        //display wages
        System.out.println("The hours and pay rates you entered are:");

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {

            System.out.printf("The total wages for Employee #%d is $%.2f\n", employeeID[i], wages);
        }

    }

}
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
Enter your 3 employees work hours and pay rate:
Employee #5678459: 35
Enter the pay rate: 21
Employee #4520125: 37
Enter the pay rate: 18.5
Employee #7895122: 39
Enter the pay rate: 37.25
The hours and pay rates you entered are:
The total wages for Employee #5678459 is $1452.75
The total wages for Employee #4520125 is $1452.75
The total wages for Employee #7895122 is $1452.75
```

Comment: TL;DR. I recommend removing (or at least simplify) the wall of text that represents the assignment requirements. Focus primarily on what you currently need: "*it only calculate the last employee, the first and second are not included*". From [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague*"

Comment: Look at how you're using and displaying wages, you'll find that to be the source of your problem... you have 1 value representing X employees

Comment: Wages should also be an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're collecting 3 different hours but only storing them in one value. The same for the wages. What happens when you store them as an array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayIG 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 3;

        //creating array
        int[] hours = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
        int[] employeeID = {5678459, 4520125, 7895122};
        double[] payRate = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
        double[] wages = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your " + NUM_EMPLOYEES + " employees work hours and pay rate:");

        //get the hours
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Employee #" + employeeID[i] + ": ");
            hours[i] = keyboard.nextInt();

            //get the hourly pay rate
            System.out.print("Enter the pay rate: ");
            payRate[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();

            wages[i] = hours[i] * payRate[i];
        }



        //display wages
        System.out.println("The hours and pay rates you entered are:");

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_EMPLOYEES; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("The total wages for Employee #%d is $%.2f\n", employeeID[i], wages[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: it wouldn't let me put payRate[i] and wages[i]. it said "the type of experssion must be the array type"

Comment: Is that where the arrays are initialized? It can’t be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Either create an array of wages or calculate wages in loop where wages are being print. And you should do assignments on your own

Comment: Ye, ive been doing this for a day and i got stuck. Nothing wrong with asking for help right?

Comment: You are always welcome to quench your thirst for knowledge, this is what stack overflow does.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 employees -> 3 wages.

But currently you're using only one variable to hold the wage: `double wages = 0;`

Hence its value is replaced for every loop.

You should create an array of length 3 to store the wages:

and in your loop, replace

```
wages = hours[i] * payRate;
```

With

```
wages[i] = hours[i] * payRate;
```

And print:

```
System.out.printf("The total wages for Employee #%d is $%.2f\n", employeeID[i], wages[i]);
```

Comment: Didn't work i tried, it said "the type of expression must be the array type"

Comment: Ya because you should declare `wages` as an array: double[] wages = new double[3]

Comment: Cheers. Please mark it answered so other people can be helped too

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wage rate at each iteration. I.e. you are only ever recording a single state of wages. Then you are iterating and displaying that one wages variable, which will always be the last calculation.

Store each "wages" value in an array like you have done with hours and you should resolve your issue.